# DJango admin is serving static files from /media instead of /static

Tags: django

When I run my django app in production mode (ie without DEBUG), my admin site tries to serve static files from "/media" instead of "/static", which causes 404s

This is what it's trying to serve.

```
GET https://<domain>/media/admin/css/base.css
```

But if I manually type in

```
https://<domain>/static/admin/css/base.css
```

It serves the static file correctly. So my "collectstatic" is working fine, but somehow the admin site is trying to serve from /media.

I don't understand what settings would cause this. Everything I search for related to this is from before django 1.4 where there was a specific setting for admin media url. Other than that I don't see anyone else having this issue.

I'm loosely following https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter-django and I'm on the latest version of django right now. I'm not sure what else to look for

A selection of settings (presumably irrelevant ones omitted)

```
#config/settings/base.py

DJANGO_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    # "django.contrib.humanize", # Handy template tags

    "django.forms",
]
# STATIC
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root
STATIC_ROOT = str(ROOT_DIR / "staticfiles")
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS
STATICFILES_DIRS = [str(APPS_DIR / "static")]
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]


# MEDIA
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root
MEDIA_ROOT = str(APPS_DIR / "media")
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-url
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

# TEMPLATES
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#templates
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-BACKEND
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#dirs
        "DIRS": [str(APPS_DIR / "templates")],
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#app-dirs
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
                "django.template.context_processors.media",
                "django.template.context_processors.static",
                "django.template.context_processors.tz",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "moment.users.context_processors.allauth_settings",
            ],
        },
    }
]
```

--

```
#config/settings/production.py
from .base import *  # noqa
from .base import env
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage"
COLLECTFAST_STRATEGY = "collectfast.strategies.filesystem.FileSystemStrategy"
ADMIN_URL = env("DJANGO_ADMIN_URL")

# Collectfast
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://github.com/antonagestam/collectfast#installation
INSTALLED_APPS = ["collectfast"] + INSTALLED_APPS  # noqa F405
```

Note that most of the static file settings are declared in my base.py, which is included when I run this in "debug" mode using config/settings/local.py. And that works fine. It's only in production mode that it's trying to serve the static files out of /media

Comment: It could be your `STATIC_URL`. Can't say much else without seeing your `settings.py`.

Comment: Can you show the settings and root URLs file

Comment: There's a lot of settings, most of which were generated from the cookiecutter app. I'll post what I think are relevant, but let me know if there's something I'm missing.

Comment: does this only happen for /admin related static files or for all?

Comment: @Razenstein it seems to only happen to admin. My site's static files are served from /static successfully. That's the only 2 things i know of that serve static files. So i can't say if it's specifically the admin module, or if it's all modules other than my own static files

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was caused by the https://github.com/antonagestam/collectfast provided by the cookiecutter template I was using. The default tried to use s3 as the static file location, and I configured it to use the local filesystem. There was probably something wrong with that configuration. I didn't look into it further. Removing the collectfast package worked